# How to find the NTh entry in a comma-separated list and keep the corresponding row?

Tags: regex

I would like to extract some rows from a large `.txt` file:

```
MYNAME, 2017-03-01, John Wayne, H\
MYNAME, 2017-01-01, Brian Wayne,P\
MYNAME, 2017-02-01, Brian Duffe, TR\
MYNAME, 2017-03-01, Iggor Miller, R\
```

Having the following  file I would like to extract only those people whose name starts with `W`:

```
MYNAME, 2017-03-01, John Wayne,H\
MYNAME, 2017-01-01, Brian Wayne,P\
```

What I have tried did not work as expected:

```
 /(?:[^\,]*\,){2}([^,]*)/
```

Where I try to get a `W`after the second `,`

Appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

[Your `(?:[^\,]*\,){2}([^,]*)` regex](https://regex101.com/r/grSqDy/1) matches any 0+ chars other than `,` followed with `,` exactly 2 times, and then 0+ chars other than `,`. Just adding `W` won't work, you need to account for the words before the family names. You might add `\s+\S+\s+W` before the last `[^,]*`, or use a PCRE regex:

```
^(?:[^,]*,){2}\h*\S+\h+W.*
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/grSqDy/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string/line
- `(?:[^,]*,){2}` - 2 occurrences of any 0+ chars other than `,` followed with `,`
- `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `\S+` - 1 or more non-whitespace chars
- `\h+` - 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `W` - a `W` char
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible

Another alternative (a JS compatible one): match all chars other than `,` after you matched two chunks of non-comma chars followed with a comma, and then match a whitespace + `W`:

```
^(?:[^,]*,){2}[^,]*\sW.*
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/grSqDy/4).

Here, `[^,]*\sW.*` matches any 0+ chars other than `,` as many as possible, and then a whitespace is matched, then `W` and then any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible (the rest of the string/line).